# Export formatted reference from biblatex file to paste in email or web page

Tags: org-mode, bibtex

I have my academic bibliography in a biblatex file. I usually write academic stuff in org-mode or latex syntax, and for those, I use either `org-cite` (with `citar`) or `ebib`.
But occasionally I also need to paste formatted references in emails or web pages. I'm looking for a way to use a csl (or else a biblatex) style to do that.

- Citar has `citar-insert-reference` but this outputs only plain text (no italic markup). The output can be customized to some extent in `citar-templates` variable, but the possibilities are very limited, compared to what a csl file can offer.
- Ebib has `ebib-copy-reference-as-kill` which also outputs to plain text. It can similarly be customized via `ebib-reference-templates`. This is slightly more flexible than the citar option since it can specify different formats for different types of bibliographic items. Still, it feels like writing a csl style specially for that purpose, which seems like an unnecessary chore.

In short: is there a way to use `org-cite` or `ebib` (or other elisp) to

1. select an item from a .bib file
2. format the full reference in org or html syntax according to a csl style
3. copy the result to the kill ring?

Comment: `citar-insert-reference` and `citar-copy-reference` can use any CSL style via citeproc-el -- you have to change the value of the `citar-citeproc-format-reference` customizable variable to `citar-citeproc-format-reference`.

Comment: Thanks! @Simka. I was not aware of those functions. Their output is far more customizable than what I had found. However, it's still plain text with no formatting instructions. I'd like to keep the csl capability to have, say, the title in italics. I don't mind the output being in org or html syntax (`/italics/` or `<em>italics</em>`) since I can then convert from one to the other using pandoc. I might have to write some elisp to export the selected references to a temp buffer, export that buffer to html, and copy the results to the kill ring?